# Structing a package in python such that external imports are not shown within submodules

Tags: python, python-import, python-module

Lets say that I have a package pkg, which contains several modules, one of which is a module1. module1 has its own function module1_foo
as well as several external imports such as numpy.

I want to structure my package so that when I call

```
import pkg
dir(pkg.modules.module1)
```

I only see module1_foo (apart from usual **xxx**) and not other external imports such as numpy.

The structure I tried is as follows

```
pkg/
    ├── __init__.p
    ├──modules/
        ├── __init__.py
        ├── module1/
        │   ├── __init__.py
        │   ├── _module1.py
```

Here

```
#pkg/__init__.py
from . import modules

#pkg/modules/__init__.py
from . import module1

#pkg/modules/module1/__init__.py
from ._module1 import *

#pkg/modules/module1/_module1.py
import numpy as _np
__all__=['module1_foo']
def module1_foo()
```

So now when I say import pkg and check dir(pkg.modules.module1), I see (apart from the usual stuff) _module1 and module1_foo. How could I get rid of _module1?

I also feel like I am obsessing too much over this but is this kind of structuring the usual practice (I tried to check structuring of some packages such as numpy and pandas but they are extremely hard to navigate).

ps: I have checked several similar topics in stackoverflow and this structure I got is actually a combination of what I saw in those topics, however could not find a complete answer to my problem.

edit: tried to emphasize the main problem as suggested

Comment: I don't see what is your problem. Could you clarify, try formating your question to emphasize main points. PS I think you can't have relative imports in `__init__.py` (but I'm not sure)

Comment: tried adding my main point at the beginning

Comment: Python cannot hide its variables (note that module *is* variable). Especially from dir. Best you could do is import external packages `as _numpy` (which is seen in a lot of standard modules). Or you could go to CPython, which can actually hide data.

Comment: Yea, I guess I will go down that road